If $\operatorname{corr}(\xi, \xi^2) = 1$, what can be suggested about $\xi$?
I have a question about what if $\operatorname{corr}(\xi, \xi^2) = 1$. I have an assumption, that $\xi$ must be a discrete random variable that can only have positive/negative values, i.e., $\xi > 0$ or $\xi < 0$.  How can I prove that there are no other possible options for $\xi$?

If Corr(X,Y)=1 then X and Y must be a multiple of each other, if you center and rescale.

Could you explain it more clearly to me? I've heard a similar explanation before, but I don't know how to express it in a more mathematical way...

Expand Var(X-aY) and solve for a so that it is zero.

$\text{Corr}(X,Y) = 1$ is equivalent to $X = a + bY$ almost surely with $b>0$ . Therefore we have a.s.
$$
\xi^2 = a + b\xi.
$$
It basically means that $\xi$ must take only two or one values which satisfy that equation for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b > 0$.

This seems extremely convincing, yet the probability distribution constructed in the other answer seems to be not of this form. I am very confused now. Does anyone know how to reconcile the two answers?

$$\text{correl} = 1\iff\left(\mathbb{E(\xi^3)}-\mathbb{E(\xi)}\mathbb{E(\xi^2)}\right)^2 =\left(\mathbb{E(\xi^2)}-\left(\mathbb{E(\xi)} \right)^2\right)\cdot \left(\mathbb{E(\xi^4)}-\left(\mathbb{E(\xi^2)} \right)^2\right) \tag{1}$$
The correlation is equal to $1$ for all random variables $\xi$ having the first 4 moments satisfying $(1)$.
Take for example, the random variable $\xi$ with:
$$\cases{\mathbb{E(\xi)}=1 \\
\mathbb{E(\xi^2)} =2\\
\mathbb{E(\xi^3)} = -1\\
\mathbb{E(\xi^4)} = 13
}$$
and for all $n \ge5$: $\mathbb{E(\xi^n)} =0$
This variable has both negative and positive values because $\mathbb{E(\xi)}>0$ and $\mathbb{E(\xi^3)}<0$.
Remark: $\xi$ is well defined by its characteristic function:
$$\varphi(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{it\xi}) =\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(it)^n}{n!}\mathbb{E}(\xi^n) = 1+it-t^2 +\frac{it^3}{6}+\frac{13}{24}t^4$$
and to obtain the density function of $\xi$, it suffices to apply the inverse formula to the characteristic function.

I am geting a bit confused about the different inversion formulas. Could you perhaps do it explicitly? I'd like to see if all mass is indeed concentrated in only (at most) two points as the other answer claims. This does not seem obvious from $\varphi$

Hmm, thinking a bit more about it it seems impossible to have $\mathbb{E}(\xi^n) = 0$ for all $n > 4$ and $\xi$ taking on only one or two values with positive probability without having $\mathbb{E}(\xi^n) = 0$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$ as well. So the two answers to this question seem incompatible. But both seem correct. What is going on here?

@Vincent I think my solution has problem because $\mathbb{E}(\xi^{2n})\ge(\mathbb{E}(\xi^n))^2 \ge ...$ and cannot be equal to $0$
